# Extract substring of a string before specific character

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuetify.js

I have this string `2022-04-01T09:00`

I want to get rid of anything after letter `T`

I can explode it based on the letter `T`, and access the first element to get this `2022-04-01`.

I wonder if there is a way to do that with JS without having to manually explode and so on...

Comment: `.replace(/T.*$/, '')` would work too, or in this case `.substr(0, 10)` because it seems it's an ISO date that will always have the first 10 characters as YYYY-MM-DD.

Answer (score 6):

A pretty simple easy to read solution would be to split the string by `T` and grab the first element like this:

```
"2022-04-01T09:00".split("T")[0]
```

Other alternatives include:

- Using `"2022-04-01T09:00".replace(/T.*$/, '')` which will `replace` everything after (and including `T`) with an empty string.
- Grabbing the first 10 characters using `"2022-04-01T09:00".substring(0, 10)`